# First I have installed caffe successful,but when I run a caffe project , cmake is ok ,and later make emits many errors

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, caffe

when I run a caffe project, this problem happens:

```
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<boost::shared_ptr<caffe::DataReader::QueuePair> >::size() const'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<boost::shared_ptr<caffe::DataReader::QueuePair> >::pop(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Datum*>::pop(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<boost::shared_ptr<caffe::DataReader::QueuePair> >::push(boost::shared_ptr<caffe::DataReader::QueuePair> const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Datum*>::try_pop(caffe::Datum**)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Datum*>::push(caffe::Datum* const&)'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<boost::shared_ptr<caffe::DataReader::QueuePair> >::BlockingQueue()'
../lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0: undefined reference to `caffe::BlockingQueue<caffe::Datum*>::BlockingQueue()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

tools/CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/build.make:129: recipe for target 'tools/compute_image_mean' failed

make[2]: *** [tools/compute_image_mean] Error 1

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:581: recipe for target 'tools/CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/all' failed

make[1]: *** [tools/CMakeFiles/compute_image_mean.dir/all] Error 2

make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try googling before asking a question.

Comment: Probably some .so files are missing on your machine and that's why you have "Undefined reference" errors because linker couldn't find definition of functions called from libcaffe.so.1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too, the answer is that caffe recently refactor the code, they delete many existed files, including data_reader.hpp, so your old caffe project does not compile with the new one anymore